# coffee script in VS2012

Tags: javascript, .net, visual-studio-2012, coffeescript

I have installed coffee script according to these steps:

http://coffeescript.org/#installation

Everything works fine. The coffee is compiled to JS after `ctrl + s`

My colleage got my code from the source control.

He tries to change the coffie and save, but no changes are made to the js file.

We have tried to install coffee throw the Nuget, but it didn't help

Any idea what could solve this?ee

Comment: Open your Command Line, go the the folder where the coffee files are and enter 

    coffee --watch --compile someFile.coffee 

Once you edit someFile.coffee , this process should automatically compile it.

Comment: I want to compile throw VS2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this:

http://vswebessentials.com/

Web Essentials is a VS2012 extension that adds support for things like [CoffeeScript](http://vswebessentials.com/features/coffeescript), including taking care of building the `.js` file for you when you save the Coffee file.

Comment: I'll add this, but why isn't Nuget install of coffeescript enough?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the NuGet version of CoffeeScript, so I can't give guidance on how to use it. However, Web Essentials takes care of all the plumbing for you, so I wouldn't worry to much unless you must run the CoffeeScript stuff as part of a command line process, or development workflow.